# make_heap not working as expected after changing value in vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, heap

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm with heaps using [make_heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/), which (hopefully) sorts a vector in decreasing value order in order to make a priority queue, but for some reason the sorting gets all wrong if I change a value and I have no idea why.

### Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<float> heap;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) heap.push_back(1e9);

    heap[0] = 0; // <=== this is a problem for make_heap

    for(int i=0;i<heap.size();i++) cout << heap[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    make_heap(heap.begin(),heap.end());

    for(int i=0;i<heap.size();i++) cout << heap[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;   

    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3468 signal:0
0 1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 
1e+09 1e+09 0 1e+09 1e+09
```

---

A funny thing is that if I change `heap[0] = 0` to a `heap.push_back(0)` before pushing the other elements the sorting works perfectly.

### Output:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3468 signal:0
0 1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 
1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 1e+09 0
```

What could it be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A heap isn't the same as being sorted. To get the elements in sorted order use `pop_heap` repeatedly.

Comment: "the sorting works perfectly" - what sorting? `std::make_heap` just makes a heap structure out of your existing elements. All you're guaranteed after using it is the sequence fulfills the properties of a heap. And the initial line of your second output where you claim you used `push_back` rather than assignment cannot possibly be true. `push_back` pushes on the end of the sequence, not the beginning. That pushed `0` should be at the end; not the beginning.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added that line before the first loop.

Comment: @GabrielRebello in that case "I change `heap[0] = 0` to a `heap.push_back(0)`" isn't true. Either way, I think you misunderstand what `make_heap` does. It lives up to its name: it makes a heap. That's it. If you want a sorted sequence use `std::sort` (though I can't imagine why you would do so for a priority queue; rather I would just use `std::priority_queue` adapter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Unspecified by the C++ standard how a standard library should implement a Heap. So you should not expect a specific arrangement. The C++ standard only specifies the behavior.

TL;DR;

There is a difference between `heap[0] = 0`and `heap.push_back(0)`. The former doesn't change the size of the container while the latter does. And the heap representatioin for odd/even sized container may be different; it doesn't matter, all we want is a heap behavior when we access it using appropriate functions.

---

Again, whenever you use functions like `std::make_heap`, you should use its associated functions (`std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap`) to access the container (this is guaranteed to maintain the heap properties of the container).

Any other modification to it may result in the container losing its heap properties. This includes:

```
heap[0] = 0;
```

And even:

```
heap.push_back(0)
```

Comment: The modification happens before the heap is made though

Comment: @harold That's exactly why I don't see a problem. I thought before using `make_heap` I could do any operation as with a common vector and the heap structure wouldn't be affected.

Comment: @GabrielRebello yes, perfectly legal. There is no real problem. The result isn't wrong, your expectation is.

Answer (score 1):

To be a valid heap, heap[i] <= heap[(i - 1) / 2] for all i > 0.

In both cases make_heap() is creating a valid heap.  The first has 5 elements, and the second has 6.  I don't understand parts of your question, but they don't seem relevant to make_heap().